# Visual studio express is too hanging when building the source code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, ssms, sql-server-2008-express, visual-web-developer-2010

I am using **Visual Web Developer 2010 Express** in my PC for building an MVC 3 application. it's working fine till I installed **Sql Server 2008
Management Studio** yesterday.

After I installed the SSMS my Visual Web Developer is hanging when I Build my MVC 3 Web application.

And when i open the project there is a message shown in the OutPut window.

```
Some of the properties associated with the solution could not be read.
```

I am clueless what happend in my PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to repair your vs 2010. and restart the PC.

please check this link you can see the step by step example

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983433(v=vs.90).aspx

hope it will help.